# How can i create a Dialog box in pure jsf1.2

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf

i want to know , how can i create a dialog box in pures jsf app.
can i us jquery ui in jsf app.
i want to see a example for dialog box with jsf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your new to jqueryui because this is pretty simple.  You can totally use the two together. We are doing so in our project.

All you have to do is call the dialog on a div that contains all of the data that you want your dialog to contain.

So, have your JSF code output into a container (div) and then call the dialog function on that div. It's really pretty simple if you think of the jqueryui as the presentation layer on top of the JSF.

The docs are here (with a good intro example):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default

Comment: No problem. If it makes sense for you and works then please mark it as the answer so this will be closed.